# using lambda to implement list function in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I want to use lambda to create a function that gets as parameter a list of pairs and returns a list of the first elements of the first list. Example:

```
function [ (1,2), (3,4) (5,6) ] = [1,3,5]
```

I'm using lambda like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
firstall [] = []
firstall ((a,b) : xs) = (\(a,b) -> a : firstall(xs))
```

maybe I'm doing it totally wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should *ALWAYS* use type signatures, especially when you are learning. If you had, you would realize that your code creates a list of functions. Haskell's type system is powerful and helpful; use it! In your case, you wanted `firstall :: [(a,b)] -> [a]`. See what happens when you add that.

Comment: What you want is `map fst`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda expression simply is never called, you only define a lambda expression, you can call it with:

```
firstall ((a,b) : xs) = ((\(a,b) -> a) (a,b) : firstall(xs))
```

Now since you use `a` and `b` in your lambda expression as well, this is asking for trouble, a more accessible version is:

```
firstall ((a,b) : xs) = ((\(c,d) -> c) (a,b) : firstall(xs))
```

In other words you "unify" `(c,d)` with `(a,b)`. You can use `a` and `b` in your lambda expression, but it makes things for yourself.

---

This being said, you can perform this task way easier:

```
firstall = map fst
```

which is short for:

```
firstall = map (\(a,b) -> a)
```

note that you don't need to specify an input parameter for `firstall`, since `map fst` is a function that will take as input a list.

---

Finally, as @DanielWagner suggests, you can simply drop the lambda expression:

```
firstall ((a,_) : xs) = (a : firstall(xs))
```

the underscore (`_`) means you are not interested in the value: you only need the first element of the tuple.

Comment: An alternative fix to providing the lambda with an argument is to drop the lambda entirely, writing `a : firstall xs` instead of `\(a, b) -> a : firstall xs` (so that the whole line becomes `firstall ((a,b) : xs) = a : firstall xs`).  I think that's probably closer to what DcCoO had in mind.